# How to execute gvim command using c++

Tags: c++, linux, vim

I need to write a code to jump to a particular given line number in gVim. But I need to do this using a C++. Is there any way to do it?

There are ways to open the gvim by executing the Linux commands using C++ code. But is there a way to execute the gVim command using the same C++ code?

Comment: Are you sure it's a _need_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the function `system` that runs linux commands? You can use it for any command and command parameters. Bellow is the example, modify it according to your requirements.

```
int line_no = 576;
std::string file_name;
std::stringstream command;
command << "gvim +" << line_no << " " << filename;
system(command.str().c_str());
```

It will execute `gvim +576 file_name`, that opens a file at a particular line in gvim.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask `vim` to run commands from the command line. See [the list of vim command line options](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#startup-options).

To position cursor on the line `num` run `vim +num filename`, for example `vim +578 filename` jumps to line 578 in the named file. `vim + filename` jumps to the last line.

Search: `vim +/pattern filename` will position cursor on the first line containing "pattern".

Other commands: `vim -c command filename` executes the ex (`:`) command. You can run up to 10 commands (up to 10 `-c` options).